# How to stop SIGTERM and SIGKILL?

Tags: php, timeout, sigkill, sigterm

I need to run a huge process which will run for like 10+ minutes. I maxed the `max_execution_time`, but in my error logs I get a SIGTERM and then a SIGKILL.

I read a little about SIGTERM and SIGKILL that they come from the daemon, but i Didn't figure out how to stop it from happening. I just need to disable it for one night.

Comment: You can't stop sigkill. Period. That's the whole point of sigkill - the ability to shut down a process that otherwise won't.

Comment: I found sth no, so nothing of this: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/8fbtw/does_anyone_know_a_way_to_prevent_sigkill/ is possible?

Comment: you're so desparate you're willing to build a custom hacked kernel? Good luck with that...

Comment: Well I really don't know any other solution right now. I need the script to run longer than it does right now and if sigkill just kills it because it's running a long time, then I don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to ignore signals, you need to find who sends them and why. If you're starting php from the command line, no one will send that signal and your script time will have *all the time*.

But if you're actually starting this process as a response to an http request, it's probably the web server of FastCGI manager that limits the amount of time it waits for the script to finish. It also may simply kill the script because client connection (between user's browser and http server) has been terminated.

So the important question you should ask yourself - what's the source of that signal and how this timeout can be increased. Please also provide all details about how you start this script and what platform you're running.

Comment: Hey, you were right. After investigating the error_log in apache2 logs I found out, that the sigterm was for something else. I don't know what it killed exactly, but in fact, the php script is executing forever.

Comment: Yeah I think I really just solved it with "ignore_user_abort" php function. Could be really just a client timeout.